# How to convert this lambda expression to linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I can't read complicated lambda expression and only the super basic lambda expression only I know I am just starting to study lambda.

As my title above how to convert this lambda into linq?

```
var train = db.Certificates
            .Join(db.TrainingSchedules, a => a.CertificateId, b => b.CertificateId, (a, b) => new { a, b })
            .Where(x => x.a.Year.Value.Year == year && x.a.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId && x.a.IsApproved.Value && x.b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
            .Select(z => z.a).Distinct().Where(q => !db.Registrations.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == empId).Select(t => t.Certificate).Any(u => u.CertificateId == q.CertificateId));
```

Can someone explain to me why it has a different variables?. Like `x , q , z , b`?

Comment: x , q , z , b are source (Certificates (Class/Table)). You can use any key word for that. and other are expression like x => x.a.Year.Value.Year == year means class Year value == year variable.

Comment: @user2960398 if that variables are from `Certificates` so i can use only x instead of x , b , z , q?

Comment: This is Linq already. What is the problem?

Comment: @Aron sorry but I thought the linq state is like this `var sample = (from a in db. ....).singleordefault();`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As my title above how to convert this lambda into linq?

Have you every worked in `Linq` to know how does it looks like ?

If the above specified code is not `Linq`, then what is `Linq`, `Lambda` is an integral part of `fluent` representation of the `Linq`, since most of the APIs would need a `Func delegate`, that's where `Lambda` comes in.

> Now regarding `x , q , z , b`, what do they represent ?

The Linq APIs are nothing but extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`, like `List<T>`, `Dictionary<TK,TV>`, whether we write the `fluent' or the`Sql`syntax these variables represent, each and every element in the collection, which is processed as part of logic provided by the`Func Delegate`, you can certainly use and should use more credible variable to represent the exact thing, similar to other parts of code where`int x, float y, DateTime z` is a bad way to code

Regarding the statement posted above consider following changes:

- Rename `a,b` as `cert,ts`, which refers to a `Certificate` and `Training Schedule` classes respectively
- Instead of generating anonymous type `new { a, b }`, create a `class` like `CerificateTrainingSchedule` that has all the elements of the `Certificate` and `Training Schedule` class respectively, it would be easier to work as you move forward
- Rename `x` as `cts`, to represent combined `CerificateTrainingSchedule`
- If its easy to read then separate `Where` clause in multiple chains, like:

  ```
  .Where(cts => cts.a.Year.Value.Year == year)
  .Where(cts => cts.a.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId)
  .Where(cts => cts.a.IsApproved.Value)
  .Where(cts => cts.b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
  ```
- Similarly the names of other variables can be modified to represent the true class and its objects, instead of random `a,b,c,d`. Also calls can be  chained for clear understanding of the logic

**Edit - // Modified Linq Query**

// Joined / Merged version of Certificate and Training Schedule, add more fields as required, current one is based on certain assumptions of the fields / properties in the Certificate & TrainingSchedule classes respectively

```
public class CertificateTrainingSchedule
{
   public int Year {get; set;} // Certificate Class Property
   public int TrainingTypeId {get; set;} // Certificate Class Property
   public bool IsApproved {get; set;} // Certificate Class Property
   public DateTime EndDate {get; set;} // TrainingSchedule Class Property
}

var train = db.Certificates
            .Join(db.TrainingSchedules, cert => cert.CertificateId, ts => ts.CertificateId, (cert, ts) => new CertificateTrainingSchedule{ Year = cert.Year, TrainingTypeId = cert.TrainingTypeId, IsApproved = cert.IsApproved,EndDate = ts.EndDate})
            .Where(cts => cts.Year == year)
            .Where(cts => cts.TrainingTypeId == trainingTypeId)
            .Where(cts => cts.IsApproved)
            .Where(cts => cts.EndDate >= DateTime.Now)
            .Select(cts => new {cts.Year,cts.TrainingTypeId,cts.IsApproved})
            .Distinct() // Allowing anonymous type to avoid IEqualityComparer<Certificate>
            .Where(certMain => !db.Registrations.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == empId)
                                                .Select(cert => new Certificate{Year = cert.Year,TrainingTypeId = cert.TrainingTypeId,IsApproved = cert.IsApproved})
                                                .Any(cert => cert.CertificateId == certMain.CertificateId))
```

Comment: Like as `user2960398` said above `x , q , b , z` are the source from `Certificates`. Can i use a single variable for the Certificates like `X` as sample?. Could you post the linq converted for that statement?. As for your answer I can't understand well because its to much for me :) but I am studying it now.

Comment: Yes you can use a Single variable, till the point compiler doesn't complain and it is not sure what does a given value usage context. I don't have all the details to write the complete query but still let me try

Comment: Alright check the attempt above, though its not easy without overall context, which is completely missing here

Comment: I would like to ask how did you come up with the `CertificateTrainingSchedule`?

Comment: As I have mentioned to avoid using Anonymous post Join, create a class that has all the fields of `Certificate` and `TrainingSchedule` classes, though it cannot be accurate, as I have no context available. You need to change it as per real properties.

Comment: i manage to do like this but I can't get through the last part `var train = (from cert in db.Certificates
                          join ts in db.TrainingSchedules on cert.CertificateId equals ts.CertificateId
                          where cert.Year.Value.Year == year && cert.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId && cert.IsApproved.Value && ts.EndDate >= DateTime.Now
                          select cert).Distinct().Where(q => !db.Registrations.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == empId).Select(t => t.Certificate).Any(u => u.CertificateId == q.CertificateId));`

Comment: You have to go slow, step by step and check the ensuing result at each step, thus you would know where its going wrong as the result is unexpected output, btw which call is causing issue / error. I cannot guess it.

Comment: at part of `.Where(q => !db.Registrations.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == empId).Select(t => t.Certificate).Any(u => u.CertificateId == q.CertificateId));` so far i manage to do it in linq but im not sure if it is okay.

Comment: Check what's the `result` of this statement separately:
`db.Registrations.Where(s => s.EmployeeId == empId).Select(t => t.Certificate)`
Then check the `result` upto `Distinct` call and manually compare them, `Any` call in the end is just for comparison to provide `boolean` for the `Where` clause

Comment: The query from `db.registrations .....` returns `Enumeration yielded no results` and the query before the distinct return a data.

Comment: My understanding is `Enumerations` as result of `db.registrations`, doesn't have data to compare with original result post `Distinct` though i see you fetching `Registrations` and `Certificate`, they don't seem to be enumerations, but classes

Comment: Sorry about this because I didn't start this code that's why I don't understand how did he use or make it.

Comment: Please understand my limitation of understanding everything from SO post, you have no option but to compare each piece separately and construct the final result

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by your question, you mean you want a query expression that is equivalent to calling the LINQ methods explicitly. Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what a correct example would be. However, the following is I believe what you're looking for:

```
var train =
    from q in
         (from x in
              (from a in db.Certificates
               join b in db.TrainingSchedules on a.CertificateId equals b.CertificateId
               select new { a, b })
          where x.a.Year.Value.Year == year && x.a.TrainingTypeId == trainingTypeId &&
                x.a.IsApproved.Value && x.b.EndDate >= DateTime.Now
          select x.a).Distinct()
     where !(from s in db.Registrations where s.EmployeeId == empId select s.Certificate)
       .Any(u => u.CertificateId == q.CertificateId)
     select q;
```

Note that not all of the LINQ methods have a C# query expression language equivalent. In particular, there's no equivalent for `Distinct()` or `Any()`, so these are still written out explicitly.

> Can someone explain to me why it has a different variables?. Like x , q , z , b?

Each lambda expression has the input on the left side of the `=>` and the result expression on the right. The variables you're referring to are the inputs. These are commonly written using single letters when writing lambda expressions, because the a lambda expression is so short, the meaning can be clear without a longer variable name. For that matter, independent lambda expressions could even use the same variable name.

Note that in the query expression syntax, not all of the variables "made it". In particular, we lost `z` and `t` because those variables were superfluous.

In an expression this long, it's possible you might find longer variable names helpful. But it's a trade-off. The query expression language is meant to provide a compact way to represent queries on data sources. Longer variable names could make it harder to understand the query itself, even as it potentially makes it easier to understand the intent of each individual part of the expression. It's very much a matter of personal preference.

Comment: To complicated for me :) your converted answer maybe I need more knowledge about linq I just use linq about 4months. This is my first time to see like that linq statement so many `(from a in db.. (from b in db...` from reading your answer im getting dizzy :D.. Like you said to become short so use a variables as for me like example a beginner how can I overcome that I can understand the variable i use is for that `table`

Comment: I try your query it has an error here `join b in schedules on a.CertificateId equals -(b.CertificateId)-`

Comment: If the expression `b.CertificateId` gives an error in the code I provided, it would produce an error in the code you provided as well. I did mention that the _only_ way for anyone to provide an answer that is _guaranteed_ to be 100% correct for your purposes, _you_ need to provide a good [mcve] in your question first. Without that, the above is the best one can hope for.

Comment: As for the nested queries, well...your original code is fairly complicated as well, and also effectively has nested queries, from the `Join()` and the multiple `Where()` calls. So it's not surprising the query expression version would be similarly complicated.

Comment: the code that I provided as sample is functioning well and it is in my current project. Sorry for the trouble because I don't understand well a lambda expression.

Comment: Did you replace the placeholder `certificates`, `schedules`, and `registrations` with your actual `db` sources? I had thought you'd at least realize you needed to do that, but maybe not. I will edit them back into the example (the code I posted is copy/pasted from _working_ code, but I had to make up the working code from scratch, because the question lacked a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

> I can't read complicated lambda expression and only the super basic lambda expression only I know I am just starting to study lambda.

Try reading this:

```
var train = db.Certificates
    .Where(c => c.Year.Value.Year == year && 
                c.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId &&
                c.IsApproved.Value &&
                c.TrainingSchedules.Any(ts => ts.EndDate >= DateTime.Now) &&
                !c.Registrations.Any(r => r.EmployeeId == empId));
```

If you can, then you are just fine.

Note that this is not an exact translation of the sample query, but is functionally equivalent (should produce the same result). The sample query is a good example of badly written query - variable naming, unnecessary multiplicative `Join` which requires then a `Distinct` operator (while `GroupJoin` would do the same w/o the need of `Distinct`), inconsistent handling of two similar detail criteria (`Join` for `TrainingSchedules` and `Any` for `Registrations`), overcomplicated criteria for `Registrations` part etc.

Shortly, don't write such queries. Concentrate on the desired result from the query and use the most logical constructs to express it. Avoid manual joins when you have navigation properties. If you don't have navigation properties, then add them to the model - it's easy one time action which helps a lot when writing queries. For instance, in my translation I assume you have something like this:

```
class Certificate
{
    // Other properties ...
    public ICollection<TrainingSchedule> TrainingSchedules { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }  
}

class TrainingSchedule
{
    // Other properties ...
    public Certificate Certificate { get; set; }  
}

class Registration
{
    // Other properties ...
    public Certificate Certificate { get; set; }  
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the same using the query syntax:

```
var train = 
    from c in db.Certificates
    where c.Year.Value.Year == year && 
          c.TrainingTypeId.Value == trainingTypeId &&
          c.IsApproved.Value &&
          c.TrainingSchedules.Any(ts => ts.EndDate >= DateTime.Now) &&
          !c.Registrations.Any(r => r.EmployeeId == empId)
    select c;
```

Comment: Great simple and short. But as for may thread I want to convert it in linq. I don't know much about how the linq statement made or done as far as i know from my knowledge the linq statement that i know is `var sample = ( from a in db. .....)singleordefault();`

Comment: It's is a LINQ. If you mean the so called "query syntax", it's quite easy.

Comment: @sorry I don't know much about that :).

Comment: See the update. It's using just pretty basic operators - `from`, `where` and `select`. To materialize the result, you just enclose it with `(...)` and append `ToList` (if you expect multiple results), `FirstOrDefault` (if you expect single result) etc.